# Need to understand logarithmic integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms

So $d/dx \ln(x) = 1/x$.
Why is $\int \frac 1 {e^y}\,dy \ne \ln(e^y)$?

Comment: You have forgotten to consider the consequences of the chain rule.

Comment: @IanMiller Could you please expand on the usage of the chain rule in this example, im missing some of the basics of calculus and really want to understand it. Thanks

Comment: If you were to differentiate your answer $\ln(e^y)$ you wouldn't stop after one step and write down $\frac{1}{e^y}$. You would follow that up with the chain rule: $\frac{1}{e^y}\times\frac{d}{dy}e^y$.

Answer (score 0):

Well

$$\int {dx\over x} = \log |x|+C$$

yes, but if you mean to integrate

$$\int {dy\over e^y}$$

in the second one the reason is obvious:  it's not ${d(e^y)\over e^y}$ in the integrand. In that case you get:

$$\int {d(e^y)\over e^y} = \int {e^y\over e^y}\,dy = y + C = \log|e^y|+C$$

as desired.